# Error occurred while analyzing the Eclemma code coverage

Tags: eclemma

I am using the `Eclemma 2.3` and as well as `lombok-1.16.8.jar`.

When I run the code coverage, **Eclemma plugin gives the following error**:

> Error while loading coverage session (code 5001).** Error while
>   analyzing package fragment root lombok-1.16.8.jar at
>   C:/Users/sudhakar_b/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.16.8/lombok-1.16.8.jar
>   (code 5007). Error while analyzing
>   C:/Users/sudhakar_b/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.16.8/lombok-1.16.8.jar@lombok/eclipse/agent/EclipseLoaderPatcherTransplants.SCL.lombok.

Comment: The issue is fixed in machine. First i ran the JUnit test cases using maven plugin. Then i ran the eclemma code coverage plugin. It works fine.

Comment: See here for further suggestions of how to resolve this error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44108835/error-while-loading-coverage-session-code-5001

Answer (score 0):

I was just having this issue and the best way for me was uninstalling `Eclemma` and re-installing it.

You can do so by clicking `Help` and selecting `Eclpise Marketplace...` from the menu.  Once there, you can search for `Eclemma` on the `Installed` tab.  Proceed to uninstall.

Once you uninstall, Eclipse will ask to restart for the software changes to take effect.  Proceed to do so.  Once Eclipse is back up, go ahead and follow the same steps except this time install `Eclemma`.

This should fix the issue`Error while loading coverage session (code 5001)`.