# Error while loading coverage session (code 5001) in eclemma plugin

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mockito, eclemma

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDNo2.png)Error while loading coverage session (code 5001).
Error while analyzing package fragment root resources at F/junit/target/test-classes (code 5007).
File not found: **file path**
File not found:**file path**

Comment: Can you provide some accompanying information so that users can more easily understand why the error is occurring, such as the data and code, as per a reproducible example?

Comment: there is no error while run as junit but when i try to run as code coverage plug-in (eclemma) it throwing this exception

Comment: You should read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: but this is spring-boot application bro!

Comment: i upload the error message bro in query

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44108835/error-while-loading-coverage-session-code-5001 Answer is here in this post for above problem.